# Magenot2: what is the use of `resource` paramerter in menu.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

i created one testing module in magento2 and for backend added menu by this code:

location of this file is Test/Seller/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
<add id="Test_Seller::seller" title="Seller" module="Test_Seller" sortOrder="40" resource="Test_Seller::seller"/>
    <add id="Test_Seller::items" title="Manage Sellers" module="Test_Seller" sortOrder="40" parent="Test_Seller::seller" action="selleradmin/manage/" resource="Test_Seller::items"/>
</menu>
</config>
```

its working fine. all parameters are clear but what is ther use of `resource` parameter in add node.
if i remove this parameter then "Missing required param resource" error is coming.

Answer (score 3):

Resource attribute  define acl resource for menu element. 
If user has not access to this resource then the menu item will be not shown for him.

Comment: but how can we map with resource, means if i am changing id of resource in acl.xml or changing resource attribute value then also menu is shown.

Comment: and what is the point of id attribute and the Module::something value in it ?